# Superimpose linetype on CI color in marginsplot legend (Stata)

Tags: graph, legend, stata

I am wondering if it's possible to superimpose linetypes (the `plotopts` argument, i.e., dot, dash, solid line, etc.) onto their corresponding CI (the `ciopt` argument, i.e., color)?

I use the following example to illustrate (please note the legend part, only CI colors are shows, although one can insert something like `order(3 "f=0's line type" 4 "f=1's line type")` to have their linetype symbol shown, but they are not superimposed on their corresponding CIs). It will be really appreciated if anyone could give me some hints.

```css
/* using the example from UCLA data archive */

use https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/logitcatcon, clear

logit y i.f##c.s, nolog
margins f, at(s=(20(5)70)) vsquish

/* plotting */
marginsplot, recast(line) recastci(rarea) ciopt(color(gs14) alwidth(none)) ci1opt(color(gs5) alwidth(none)) plotopts(lc(gs0) lpattern(dot)) plot1opts(lc(gs0) lpattern(solid)) legend(order(1 "f=0" 2 "f=1") rows(1))
```

[image]

Comment: I don't follow this. From the image above, and from running the code, the line types are indeed dotted and solid. Incidentally, I would apply transparency for a graph like this.

Comment: I'm still running on Stata 14 (which does not support the transparency option), I guess this causes the line types to be suppressed by CI colors(?)

Comment: I don't have access to Stata 14, only 16, but your image shows dots and solid lines, so it seems that you are getting what you asked for. It's generally good practice to lay down areas first before lines or points and `marginsplot` seems to be doing that, although I am too lazy to inspect the code.

Comment: I mean superimposing line types on CI color in the legend (at the bottom of the graph).

Comment: I see. That's hard. A legend maps one-to-one to the variables shown, so you can show a patch of area or a segment of line type but not both so far as I know. Not the answer you want but here and very often a legend is at best a necessary evil. I would lose the legend and put direct labels `f = 0` and `f = 1` above and below the curves in the plot region wherever there is space (or, naturally, better explanatory text explaining what 0 and 1 mean);

Answer (score 0):

Change the 1 and 2 in your legend command to 3 and 4. Stata treats these as four graphs.
Change: legend(order(1 "f=0" 2 "f=1")
To: legend(order(3 "f=0" 4 "f=1")
I had the same issue!